# PHP Soap Client - sending the wrong headers "soapenv:VersionMismatch"

Tags: php, soap, request, version

I've come across a problem that I cannot figure out how to fix. I've created a soap client in php that is supposed to do an xml request to a web service - the service is working through SoapUI, but whenever I send the same request through my php client I get the following faultcode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>**soapenv:VersionMismatch**</faultcode>
      <faultstring>**Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI**</faultstring>
      <detail></detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, both the client and the service are working with soap version 1.2, I believe that the problem is in the client, so here it is how I've defined it:

```
$options  = array(
    'trace'        => true, 
    'exceptions'   => 1, 
    'style'        => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'use'          => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
);
$client = new SoapClient("location_of_the_wsdl", $options);
```

In the request I'm using the following code:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ns2:FunctionName xmlns:ns2="namespace_of_the_service">
         <arg0>
              <data1>?</data1>
           </arg0>
       </ns2:FunctionName>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

In soapUI this is giving me a 'false' result as the data1 is left with ?, when I write in valid data it returns true.

I've also noticed that in soapUI I'm sending and receiving the Content-type `application/soap+xml`, but when I'm doing it through the PHP client I send and receive headers with Content-Type `text/xml`;

What could be the problem? I use `nusoap.php` for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **WSDL caching feature** is disabled in php.ini file of your development (test) machine by setting

```
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0
```

I got stocked in this problem for more than 1 day only because of cached WSDL :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using SOAP version 1.2 to make your calls. Can you check if the version used by the web service is indeed 1.2 and not 1.1.

Comment: I did. It is 100% 1.2 - if I change the version in the client call, I get an error of mismatched versions but with faultstring of 'you can use only SOAP 1.2' :/

Comment: Ok. What are the headers you are using? `Content-Type` etc. Can you post them here.

Comment: I do believe the problem must be in the nusoap.php of SourceForge - according to this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/forums/forum/193578/topic/3947116 when I use soap 1.2 things in the requests it won't work, so right now I'm re-writing the nusoap to work with soap 1.2 - hopefully this will fix the problem. But any other ideas are welcome (or solutions to use soap 1.2 with some other php class like nusoap)

Comment: See these threads - http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/13879/9873/, http://wso2.org/library/559